# Dependencia circular com FluentValidation

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Dado o exemplo abaixo:

```cs
public class ObjectA
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObjectB AnotherObject { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObjectA AnotherObject { get; set; }
}
```

Com seus respectivos validadores:

```cs
public class ObjectAValidator : AbstractValidator<ObjectA>
{
    public ObjectAValidator(IValidator<ObjectB> validator)
    {
        this.RuleFor(c => c.Name).NotNull();
        this.RuleFor(c => c.AnotherObject).SetValidator(validator);
    }
}

public class ObjectBValidator : AbstractValidator<ObjectB>
{
    public ObjectBValidator(IValidator<ObjectA> validator)
    {
        this.RuleFor(c => c.Name).NotNull();
        this.RuleFor(c => c.AnotherObject).SetValidator(validator);
    }
}
```

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<ObjectA>();
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var objetoAValidator = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IValidator<ObjectA>>();

        ObjectA test = new()
        {
            Name = "1Level",
            AnotherObject = new()
            {
                Name = "2Level",
                AnotherObject = new()
                {
                    AnotherObject = new()
                }
            }
        };

        var validationResult = objetoAValidator.Validate(test);
    }
}
```

O modelo acima, dispara o seguinte erro:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A circular dependency was detected for the service of type 'FluentValidation.IValidator<ConsoleApp9.ObjectA>'.
> FluentValidation.IValidator<ConsoleApp9.ObjectA>(ConsoleApp9.ObjectAValidator) -> FluentValidation.IValidator<ConsoleApp9.ObjectB>(ConsoleApp9.ObjectBValidator) -> FluentValidation.IValidator<ConsoleApp9.ObjectA>'

Como posso resolver o problema de dependência circular na validação de modelos que se auto referenciam utilizando `FluentValidation`?

Existe alguma outra abordagem para isso?

Comment: Na sua classe de validação 'ObjectAValidator : AbstractValidator<ObjectA>' você recebe ObjectB em seu método e na classe de validação 'ObjectBValidator : AbstractValidator<ObjectB>' você recebe ObjectA. Pergunta, é esse o seu objetivo?